# how to populate the textboxes inside a gridview from a datagrid in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a gridview in my form.aspx page. The textboxes in each row of the gridview are to be populated  from a datagrid upon clicking a particular field of the datagrid. Is there any way to do the same.....?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out some of the samples the [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) website? Maybe this one can help?

[Gridview quickstart on ASP.NET](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)

Otherwise I suggest you describe your problem in greater details. What's the datasource? Anything specific you can't figure out right now? Are you getting any exceptions?